# Get required/non-null field on introspection

Tags: graphql

I'm using an introspection to query InputTypes to generically create a form to alter an entity.

```
query introspection($updateInputName: String!) {
  __type(name: $updateInputName) {
    inputFields {
      name
      type {
        name
        kind
        ofType {
          kind
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I understood the type.kind information should return NON_NULL for required/non-null fields. But I receive SCALAR, ...

How can I get the information about the required fields of the queried inputField?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `kind` field will indeed resolve to `NON_NULL` if the field is non-nullable. If you are seeing `SCALAR`, then the field is nullable.

Here's how an introspection result would look like for each combination of wrapper types:

`Int`

```
"type": {
  "name": "Int",
  "kind": "SCALAR",
  "ofType": null
}
```

`Int!`

```
"type": {
  "name": null,
  "kind": "NON_NULL",
  "ofType": {
    "name": "Int",
    "kind": "SCALAR",
    "ofType": null
  }
}
```

`[Int!]`

```
"type": {
  "name": null,
  "kind": "LIST",
  "ofType": {
    "name": null,
    "kind": "NON_NULL",
    "ofType": {
      "name": "Int",
      "kind": "SCALAR",
      "ofType": null
    }
  },

}
```

`[Int!]!`

```
"type": {
  "name": null,
  "kind": "NON_NULL",
  "ofType": {
    "name": null,
    "kind": "LIST",
    "ofType": {
      "name": null,
      "kind": "NON_NULL",
      "ofType": {
        "name": "Int",
        "kind": "SCALAR",
        "ofType": null
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: You're right. I was looking at the wrong Type of my schema and got confused.